# Integration GitLab with Git repositories

Tags: ubuntu, git, gitlab

I have a GitLab on my server, and of course Git as my repository system.

But I have problem integrating them with each other. It looks like I am creating project in GitLab and add README file (repositories are stored as I see in `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories`).

So project should be created in repository `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/wojsza`, all I see in this folder is project name with git extension (in this case `playground.git`).

When I try to do `git status` or `git remote -v` I am getting

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Same thing if I try to clone it (`git clone git@example.com:wojsza/playground.git`)

```
fatal: 'wojsza/playground.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But when I making some new repository manuall using `git init` in my home folder it works and I can clone it, but it is not recognized in GitLab.

What could be the source root of this problem.

Comment: The *folders* named `something.git` are (supposed to be) Git repositories. They’re bare repositories, of course.

Comment: Maybe you can't clone it because it's empty initially. Try to add it as a remote to some other repo and push to it.

Comment: I am unclear about where you are creating the project and what the server has to do with anything. A Git-related server is just a server you push and pull to. A local repository is a local repository. Peeking into `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories` is not something you would ever do in normal operations.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you (usually) use a Gitlab repository, or any web-hosted Git repo (Gitlab, Github, Bitbucket...)

The Gitlab repo is intended to be used as a remote, not a local repository.

On the Gitlab project homepage, there is a "Clone" button. It contains an URL, SSH or HTTPS (or both) depending on your Gitlab config. This URL must be used on your computer in a `git clone` command in order to create a local instance of the project, you can then issue `git push` and `git pull`s to send your modifications to the Gitlab repo.

Here, on the Gitlab page for Gitlab CE:

[image: "Clone" button on the right side of the project page]

---

*Edit*

Another cool thing: depending on your Gitlab config, you can create a local git repo on your computer with `git init`, then ad a **non-exisiting** Gitlab project as a remote with

```
git remote add origin https://gitlab.example.com/path/to/repo.git
```

Then on the first `git push`, the corresponding Gitlab project and repo will be created. It depends on your Gitlab config and may not be authorized on your instance. And you may need to explicitely specify the branch to push since your local branch will not have any tracking/remote branch set.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and I solved it by giving the whole URL while cloning repo. In your case: 
`git clone git@example.com:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/wojsza/playground.git`